# Fill text in selected field from active window - VBScript, WScript.Shell

Tags: shell, vbscript, wscript.shell

I use vbs to upload files into SAP. After clicking "add file" in sap I have the following window on the screen.

[image: popup window]

I can't control that window using SAP Object so I use `WScript.Shell`. My question is - how to paste text (file path) to the field "File name:"? I was using `wshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"` to jump from one field to another and paste file path, but somehow it doesn't work always. How to get control over that field "File name:" directly and edit it's value?

My code here:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
filePath = "C:\image.png"

wshShell.AppActivate("Storing Files in Documents")
  WScript.sleep 200
wshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
  WScript.sleep 200
wshShell.SendKeys filePath
  WScript.sleep 200
wshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit
```

Regards

Comment: The underscored letters will activate the relevant option with the appropriate modifier key.  As the file name has an underscore on `n` try sending Alt & n or Ctrl & n - this should select the file name field for you to edit.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that, it works much better.